# SQL Server Indexes Aren't Helping

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2000

I have a table (SQL 2000) with over 10,000,000 records.  Records get added at a rate of approximately 80,000-100,000 per week.  Once a week a few reports get generated from the data.  The reports are typically fairly slow to run because there are few indexes (presumably to speed up the INSERTs).  One new report could really benefit from an additional index on a particular "char(3)" column.

I've added the index using Enterprise Manager (Manage Indexes -> New -> select column, OK), and even rebuilt the indexes on the table, but the SELECT query has not sped up at all.  Any ideas?

**Update**:

Table definition:

```
ID, int, PK
Source, char(3)  <--- column I want indexed
...
About 20 different varchar fields
...
CreatedDate, datetime
Status, tinyint
ExternalID, uniqueidentifier
```

My test query is just:

```
select top 10000 [field list] where Source = 'abc'
```

Comment: Table definition and query string are needed to answer this question. The error might be entirely somewhere else.

Comment: Also post the EXPLAIN results

Comment: How many distinct values are in Source, in comparison to the number of table rows? Is the index CLUSTERED or not?

Comment: Another index is the CLUSTERED index.  There are currently about 400 options for Source, although some are used much more frequently than others.

Comment: In relation to millions of table rows 400 distinct values are not much in terms of selectivity. Maybe the index isn't even used because of that. Try making Source the CLUSTERED index.

Comment: How slow are we talkinmg about?

Comment: "Try making Source the CLUSTERED index." Gulp. Might want to throw another field into the index for that much work.

Comment: My sample query above takes 70 seconds, where a query where ID >= [somevalue] takes ~2 seconds. ID, the PK, is the CLUSTERED index.  In production, queries are slightly more complex and are taking several minutes to complete.  I already know some query optimizations I can make there once I get this.

Comment: @doofledorfer: How is "throwing in another field" going to make any difference when the query just filters on *that one* field?

Comment: I'm assuming there are potentially other queries that would benefit from a compound key. And as long as you're sorting the whole file anyway, there's no cost. Make it as selective as possible.

Comment: A compound key is only useful if you actually query the components *together*. If no such case exists, the compound key is just more work at the INSERT. The ID for example should live as it's own index, because it is likely to be queried on it's own.

Comment: There would be not point to making a compound index including a unique column, forget how likely it is to be queried alone. But you only get one clustered index, so make it as compound as possible if there's any possibility of using multiple columns. This 3-caracter Source is a perfect candidate.

Comment: My point is: The clustered index over (a ASC, b ASC) won't buy you a lot if you filter on "b" alone, because "b" will be cluttered all over the index. So throwing another field in makes no sense you are not going to ask for all fields in the index at the same time.

Comment: @Tomalak, "In relation to millions of table rows 400 distinct values are not much in terms of selectivity" Huh? .25% is just as selective for 1MM rows as it is 1K rows, it's a percentage. The real question is what's the clustering factor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look at the query plan and see if it is using that new index - if it isnt there are a couple things. One - it could have a cached query plan that it is using that has not been invalidated since the new index was created. If that is not the case you can also trying index hints [ With (Index (yourindexname)) ].

10,000,000 rows is not unheard of, it should read that out pretty fast.

Comment: "it should read that out pretty fast" that's a bold statement, given the fact that you know zero about the hardware configuration, SQL server version, RAM amount , other load, disk setup, ...)

Comment: This was the "hint" I needed (pun intended).  Query now runs in < 2 seconds.  Thank you.

Comment: Tomalak - good point. I was just making a general assumption but it seems that he was successful.

Comment: So I think this shows that the index was not used automatically because of it's low selectivity, and a full table scan occurred instead.

Comment: I would be interested to see if after providing the hint, if he ran the query without the hint if the QP changed its plan to scan that index. I doubt it is a cardinality issue with 10m records but he never told us about that column itself and what it represented.

Comment: If I run it with the hint then again without the hint, it is still slow without it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Show Execution Plan in SQL Query Analyzer to see if the index is used.

You could also try making it a clustered index if it isn't already.

Answer (score 0):

For a table of that size your best bet is probably going to be partitioning your table and indexes.

Comment: Do you have any idea how much effect this would have? How can you say "probably"? How probable? How much effort should they spend? How would they weigh whether it's a good idea? It sounds a lot like "try this, try that".

Comment: It will have an effect, but I have no way to tell you how much. Is it better to use a HashTable or search sequentially through a list when looking for an item? Divide and conquer works. That's CS1.

Comment: CS1 is *not* that you should probably partition your big tables and indexes because it might help.

Comment: It's going to hurt on inserts, but you are telling me it won't help on reads? Seriously?

Comment: I'm saying it's a matter of how much hurt, and how much help. It's not worth all the implementation and support overhead for a .05% gain; which is entirely possible. I'm saying your suggestion is pretty random if you don't qualify or compare it and just say "probably", as if it were obvious.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select top 10000
```

How unique are your sources? Indexes on fields that have very few values are usually ignore by the SQL engine. They make queries slower. You might want to remove that index and see if it is faster if your SOURCE field only has a handful of values.